# Как настроить связку apache-php-mysql?

Tags: apache, php, mysql

Помогите пожалуйста, как правильно настроить связку apache-php-mysql! Я в этом деле новичок просто). Пробовал настроить сам, установил apache 2.2 в users/public (у меня windows 7) localhost работает, потом установил php в program files, а теперь самое интересное:
связать apache и php не могу! Посмотрел на сайтах как это делается, но у меня, после этого, apache при запуске ошибку теперь выдаёт.

Comment: Гугл молчит? Мануалов просто море!

Comment: он то не молчит, но после него я и не смог нормально настроить)
может здесь кто-то выложит нормальный мануал?

Comment: Протокол ошибки в студию!

Answer (score 3):

Лично мой совет такой: если новичок, то понять как настроить - трудно, тем более что нюансов много, и, тем более, не понимая, КАК это работает, еще труднее. Поэтому лучше действительно пойти другим путем - ставишь DENWER или XAMPP, начинаешь работать. Через некоторое время, когда уже свободно будешь писать на PHP, ты будешь и понимать весь принцип работы серверной части. И как раз тогда ты сам уже сможешь, абсолютно понимая и разбираясь в том что ты делаешь, настроить Apache с PHP с нуля.

Answer (score 1):

Можете попробовать XAMPP.

Answer (score 0):

Скачайте и установите DENWER (джентльменский набор веб-разработчика) - все проблемы решатся сразу :-)

Comment: Да, денвер у меня стоит, но я хотел бы научиться настраивать apache всё-таки, т.к. на реальном сервере мне это пригодится, наверное.

Comment: Ставьте Apache + PHP + MySQL + [Perl] на Linux. Я считаю, что эта комбинация на Windows - извращение.
И вообще почему apache установлен в users/public, а не program files?

Comment: да прочитал кое-где, что в windows 7 могут быть проблемы с правами доступа, а в xp хоть куда ставь))

Comment: В W7 нужно изначально ставить с правами администратора - тогда проблем не будет.

Comment: ok, спасибо за совет)

Comment: @allash 
> но я хотел бы научиться настраивать apache всё-таки, т.к. на реальном сервере мне это пригодится, наверное

Боевой сервер Apache + PHP на Windows? Ох, вряд ли это вам пригодится =) Либо ставьте IIS, либо изучайте *nix

Answer (score 0):

http://php.ru/manual/ слева пункт "установка и настройка"